# javax.el.ELException: Could not find property actionMethod in class com.example.Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

While deploying GAE + primefaces application, I got following error:

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException: Error Rendering View[/CreateEmployee.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /CreateEmployee.xhtml: Could not find property saveEmployee in class com.fetchinglife.domain.data.dao.EmployeeRepositoryImpl
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
```

Even `saveEmployee` is already in `EmployeeRepositoryImpl` class. How is this caused and how can I solve it? Are there any annotations which I have to put extra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's rephrase the exception in a general format in order to better understand the cause:

> javax.el.ELException: Could not find property doSomething in class com.example.Bean

This exception is literally trying to tell you that the `Bean` class doesn't have the following method:

```
public SomeObject getDoSomething() {
    return someObject;
}
```

*(where `SomeObject` is the type of the `doSomething` property)*

There are several causes for this.

#### Action method expression is incorrectly interpreted as property value expression

Given the fact that the property name is in your case actually a combination of a verb and noun, a resonable cause is you incorrectly bound an action method to an attribute of some JSF component which actually takes a value expression, not a method expression. E.g. when you accidentally do

```
<h:commandButton value="#{bean.doSomething}">Save</h:commandButton>
```

or even

```
<h:button value="Save" outcome="#{bean.doSomething}" />
```

instead of

```
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.doSomething}" />
```

The latter would then expect the following method, which you probably *actually* have:

```
public String doSomething() {
    // ...
    return "nextpage";
}
```

*(which can also be declared to return `void` by the way)*

#### Component is not resolved at all

Another probable cause is that the component is not interpreted as a real component at all, but as "plain text". In other words, when you remove the `action` attribute and then try to open the JSF page in browser, it'll now load fine, but you will see the whole component unparsed in the generated HTML output (which you can see via rightclick, *View Source* in browser).

This can have several causes:

1. The XML namespace of the component is wrong or missing. E.g. in case of PrimeFaces you accidentally used the old PrimeFaces 2.x URI while you're actually using PrimeFaces 3+.

   ```
    <html ... xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
   ```
2. The XML namespace URI contains a typo.

   ```
    <html ... xmlns:p="http://primefaecs.org/ui">
   ```
3. The XML namespace prefix does not match.

   ```
    <html ... xmlns:pf="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   ```
4. The XML namespace is totally missing.

   ```
    <html ...>
   ```
5. The component library is not installed at all. In other words, the JARs containing component library's tag definitions is missing in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Either way, all `<p:xxx>` tag won't be parsed and be considered as template text. But, all EL expressions will still be evaluated (as if you're using `<p>#{bean.text}</p>`), and they will all behave as `ValueExpression`s instead of `MethodExpression`s.

An easy way to recognize the root cause is looking at stack trace. If you're seeing `com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction` in the stack trace, then it means that the component is interpreted as "plain text". Otherwise you would have seen e.g. `org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton` in the specific case of `<p:commandButton>`.

Comment: :As you mentioned I have used the same , like, <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{employeeRepositoryImpl.saveEmployee}" /> and the error is like,Uncaught exception from servlet javax.el.ELException: /CreateEmployee.xhtml: Could not find property saveEmployee in class com.fetchinglife.domain.dat....

Comment: And you don't have another `#{employeeRepositoryImpl.saveEmployee}` elsewhere in the view?

Comment: As BalusC said, this is pretty much the only explanation. Somewhere in your page, you must be trying to bind #{employeeRepositoryImpl.saveEmployee} as a value rather than a method.

Comment: In my case the getter was private instead of public. Check it two times if you think everything is correct.