# Explicit url redirect in JSF 2.0

Tags: url, jsf, redirect

I have the following two pages below.

**hello.xhtml**, rendered by .../hello.jsf url.

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response"/>
</h:form>
```

**response.xhtml**, rendered by .../response.jsf url.

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandButton id="back" value="Back" action="hello"/>
</h:form>
```

When Submit button is clicked, the hello page is redirected to the response page but the url remains the same, i.e., the url is still .../hello.jsf.

I'd like the url to be **.../response.jsf** after the Submit button is clicked. Any help, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add the `redirect` attribute to your `faces_config.xml` file like so:

```
 <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/hello.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>response</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/response.xhtml</to-view-id>
       <!--the redirect element -->
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

EDIT:  I got the impression that you're using a `faces-config.xml` from your navigation outcome styling. I have confirmed personally that what you're doing is also permissible for the new JSF 2 style navigation. See BalusC's answer for using the `redirect` url parameter in a JSF2-style navigation handling

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually not using old fashioned JSF navigation cases as implied by kolossus, but are instead using new JSF2 implicit navigation feature, then just add `faces-redirect=true` query string parameter to the outcome.

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response?faces-redirect=true" />
</h:form>
```

**However**, if you don't need to invoke any bean action at all, and intend to use plain page-to-page navigation, then it makes no sense to perform a POST request for this. Just use the `<h:button>` then.

```
<h:button id="submit" value="Submit" outcome="response" />
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)

Comment: Didn't know one could get away with not adding the page extension in the view type navigation. It's why it looked like old-style nav to me