# Cannot redirect using c:redirect in JSF using JSTL

Tags: jsf, jstl

My **adminPanel.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:redirect url="http://www.google.com"></c:redirect>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run above code, I get:

> HTTP Status 500 - /loggedIn.xhtml @12,44  Tag Library
>   supports `namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`, but no tag was
>   defined for name: redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<c:redirect>` tag is not available in the Facets 2.0 . For list of available or supported tags . see [Tag Library Documentation Generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/). You can make use of jsf page navigation to redirect.

**Similar thread :**

[Explicit url redirect in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328577/explicit-url-redirect-in-jsf-2-0)

**Also tutorials:**

- [jsf page-forward Vs page-redirect](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-page-forward-vs-page-redirect/)
- [jsf-2 Redirect](http://www.javabeat.net/jsf-2-redirect-navigation/)