# PrimeFaces CommandButton that Doesn't Process Data

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF/PrimeFaces form page set up to edit some configuration details.  At the bottom are Submit and Cancel buttons implemented as `CommandButton`.  The Cancel button looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton
        action="priorPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
        value="Cancel" />
```

The problem is that the view bean still winds up doing more processing on the data that's been entered into the form than I'd like.  It isn't updating anything in the database, but if (say) I enter a string into a field that's looking for a numeric in the bean, it still produces errors.

Part of my solution is, of course, to get the bean to gracefully handle that sort of bad data, and I'm working on it.  But I'd also like to tweak that button so that it just takes the user to the prior page.  Is there some attribute I can set that will prevent the form from being processed at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<p:commandButton>` submits the form. You don't want to submit the form. You should then not use the `<p:commandButton>`, but just `<p:button>`.

```
<p:button value="Cancel" outcome="priorPage.xhtml" />
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)