# JSF Concat String with Method

Tags: jsf-2, el

How do I concat a String on the result of a method expression?
The below doesnt work.

```
<h:commandButton action="/product.xhtml?product=#{productBean.product} ">  </h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed not a valid method expression. If you intend to invoke some business action, you need to include `/product.xhtml?product=` in the return value.

```
<h:commandButton value="View" action="#{productBean.view}" />
```

With

```
public String view() {
    // ...

    return "/product.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&product=" + product;
}
```

*(the `faces-redirect=true` will make it a redirect which is most likely what you're trying to accomplish here)*

Or, if you don't need to invoke a business action at all, use `<h:button>` instead.

```
<h:button value="View" outcome="/product.xhtml?product=#{productBean.product}" />
```

Or if it's a non-numeric string which thus needs to be URLEncoded, nest it as `<f:param>`

```
<h:button value="View" outcome="/product.xhtml">
    <f:param name="product" value="#{productBean.product}" />
</h:button>
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)