# Addressbar won't update using p:commandButton for navigation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, navigation

I am using a `<p:commandButton>` for navigation and set `ajax="false"`, however the addressbar won't update to match the target page as defined in `action`-attribute. It still shows the address of the initial page with the `<p:commandButton>`.
I could swear it was not always like that. Is this behaviour normal?
How could I fix this still using `<p:commandButton>` for navigation?

my code:

```
<p:commandButton value="speichern" action="secondPage" ajax="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior if you fire a POST request. The `<form action>` as generated by `<h:form>` defaults to the current URL (rightclick, *View Source* in browser to see it yourself). Exactly this URL get reflected in browser address bar. If you want to change it after POST, you need to send a redirect afterwards. A redirect basically instructs the client to send a new GET request on the given URL. This will get reflected in browser address bar. This can be done by adding `faces-redirect=true` query string parameter to the outcome value.

```
<p:commandButton value="speichern" action="secondPage?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false"/>
```

However, using POST for navigation is bad for [UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) and [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). Just use GET in first place.

```
<p:button value="speichern" outcome="secondPage"/>
```

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)
- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton/13072025#13072025)