# Button as link, <h:button outcome /> not working (no navigation cases used)

Tags: jsf, button, hyperlink

I am trying to achieve the following, though with a button.

```
<h:outputLink value="/admin/category/read">
    Cancel
    <f:param name="cat" value="" />
    <f:param name="subcat" value="" />
</h:outputLink>
```

I have tried using `h:button`, though the `outcome` property does not work since `/admin/category/read` is not a specified navigation-case.

How to use a button as link, without having to use a navigation-case or server side method?

Comment: You could use css to make your link look like a button.

Comment: There's no solution using JSF attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no solution using JSF attributes, at least not if you really don't have a navigation case for the `h:button`.

If possible, I'd advise to use CSS styling as already mentioned in the comments.

But `h:button` just creates a plain HTML link with `onclick="window.location.href=URL"`. So if you really want, you can build the URL yourself and just use a plain HTML input button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel"
       onclick="window.location.href='/admin/category/read?cat=&subcat='; return false;" />
```

**Related:**

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)