# JSF replacing <p:button> with <h:commandLink>

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a working `<p:button>` that invokes a method inside a managed bean as follows:

```
        <h:form id="loginForm">
                <p:button value="Facebook Connect"
                    href="#{loginPageCode.facebookUrlAuth}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputText value="#{loginPageCode.userFromSession}"/>
        </h:form>
```

and i decided to replace it with a link, so i did the following:

```
      <h:form id="loginForm">

        <h:commandLink action="#{loginPageCode.getFacebookUrlAuth}"
            value="#{loginPageCode.userFromSession}" />
    </h:form>
```

but unfortunately the `<h:commandLink>` doesn't invoke the method but i don't know why?

Note: the method inside the managed bean returns a URL to a servlet, so the commandLink have to call these servlet when its clicked using the URL returned>

Comment: refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked

Comment: Set Project Stage to development you'll probably find "Unable to find matching navigation case .." after clicking on link. The values for navigation which can be used for p:button and h:commandLinks can be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There'a a major misunderstanding going here. The `<p:button>` does not invoke an action method in a managed bean at all. The EL expression in the `href` attribute is not evaluated when the button is pressed. It is evaluated when the HTML representation of the button is to be rendered. If you put a break point on the getter of `facebookUrlAuth`, then you'll see that it's invoked when the page with the button is displayed and not when the button is pressed. If you check the JSF-generated HTML output by rightclick, *view source*, then you'll see that the button navigates by JavaScript in onclick. It's a pure navigation button, not a submit button.

The `<h:commandLink>` generates a link which uses JavaScript to submit a parent form. It is not designed to perform pure navigation. For that you should be using `<h:outputLink>`, `<h:link>` or even `<a>` instead. As it's apparently an external URL, the `<h:link>` is insuitable.

Thus, so

```
<h:outputLink value="#{loginPageCode.facebookUrlAuth}">Facebook Connect</h:outputLink>
```

or just

```
<a href="#{loginPageCode.facebookUrlAuth}">Facebook Connect</a>
```

This all would have been more straightforward if you **understand** that JSF is merely a HTML code generator and when you're familiar with basic HTML.

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/)

Comment: please, is there's a way in primefaces that underlines an <h:outputLink> on mouseover or i should use javascript to do that?

Comment: i disabled the default underline as follows <h:outputLink id="notify" style="text-decoration:none;"> and want to underline the link on mouseover

Comment: Just use the CSS `:hover` pseudoselector. It's not different from when you'd do it on a plain HTML `<a>` element. Learn basic HTML/CSS as well.

Comment: As a side note / addition, if some business action is to be executed before connecting to Facebook (like logging), OP could use `<h:commandLink>` and send a redirect in an action method. Of course, it could be placed in a separate form.

Answer (score 0):

When using   you are just creating a simple HTML link on the page.
when you click on it, an HTTP GET is executed from the browser.
And with this syntax you don't need any  at all. There is no form submit

When using  and   you are using a standard JSF form submit
with the input you could have keyed in.
In your case :

value is the label of yout button
execute is a java method on your bean.

```
public String execute()
{
  return "nextPage";
}
```

JSF uses the return of this mececute method to navigate "inside" JSF, 
So "nextPage" could be an alias to a navigation rule in the faces-config.xml
or with JSF2 the name of JSF page : nextPage.xhtml.

In your case #{loginPageCode.getFacebookUrlAuth} would return a String like : "http://www.facebook.com/help/usernames"

and JSF cannot navigate with that : it is not an alias nor a page.