# Action of <p:commandButton> inside <ui:fragment rendered> is not invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to do something like this (redirect to a different page depending on some condition!):

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{projectPageBean.availableMethods}">
    <p:commandButton id="test"
        value="View Instrument"
        action="instrumentLayout?faces-redirect=false"/>                                 
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not projectPageBean.availableMethods}">
    <p:commandButton id="test1"
        value="View Instrument"
        action="methodLayout?faces-redirect=false"/>       
</ui:fragment>
```

But this construction doesn't seem to work; the page redirect in the action attributes is never carried out!

How can I get this behaviour right?

Comment: @cobalt: Neither `<ui:fragment>` nor `<h:panelGroup>` are specific to RichFaces/PrimeFaces. They are just part of standard JSF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During processing the form submit, the `rendered` attribute of the input/command component and all of its parents is re-evaluated as part of safeguard against tampered requests. If it evaluates `false`, then any child input/command components won't be decoded and the submitted values won't be set and invoked actions won't be queued.

Apparently that's what's happening here. Placing the bean in the view scope should solve it.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProjectPageBean {}
```

This way the bean will live as long as you interact with the same view by (ajax) postbacks.

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) - point 5
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's however quite strange to use command buttons for plain page-to-page navigation. Better use regular buttons for that.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{projectPageBean.availableMethods}">
    <p:button id="test"
        value="View Instrument"
        outcome="instrumentLayout"/>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not projectPageBean.availableMethods}">
    <p:button id="test1"
        value="View Instrument"
        outcome="methodLayout"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

This will also solve the concrete problem. It will just send a plain GET request on the specified URL instead of performing a postback causing all the JSF form processing to run which in turn ultimately sends another GET request as redirect. Much less clumsy thus. Note that you can safely put those buttons outside `<h:form>` this way.

If you make them `<h:link styleClass="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all">` instead of `<p:button>`, then it's even much more SEO friendly (i.e. searchbots like Googlebot can better find and index them).

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton/)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/15523045#15523045)

Comment: Thank you very, very much for the explanation and suggestion! By the way I'm fairly new to JSF and still looking for a good book covering this topic! Any suggestions will be very much welcomed!

Comment: As to the book; most of JSF can easily be understood if basic HTTP and HTML is properly understood and you know what HTML those JSF components generate. Then, to dive further into JSF consider "Core JavaServer Faces" or if you want to take JPA/EJB into account (recommended!), then "Beginning Java EE 6/7".

Comment: Thanks again, I'll certainly consider the suggestions!