# JSF redirect via commandButton

Tags: jsf

I cannot redirect to another page if the code is like this:

```
<h:commandButton type="button" value="Enter" action="index?faces-redirect=true" >
```

But the redirect works if the code is:

```
<h:commandButton type="button" value="Enter" action="index?faces-redirect=true" >
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandButton>
```

Could anyone explain this? Thanks!

-----------------------EDIT------------------------

The entire xhtml code for your reference:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton id="enterModelButton" type="button" value="Enter" action="index?faces-redirect=true" >
        <f:ajax />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `<h:commandButton type="button">` doesn't generate a submit button. It just generates a "dead" button without any effects, purely intented to be used for custom `onclick="..."` scripts and like. This is somewhat a leftover of the dark JSF 1.0/1.1 era, when it wasn't nicely possible to just use plain vanilla HTML in JSF for this kind of things.

The `<f:ajax>` performs the submit by ajax powers through JSF-generated `onclick`. It doesn't care about the button's `type`.

Essentially, removing `type="button"` and relying on its default `type="submit"` should fix your problem.

```
<h:commandButton value="Enter" action="index?faces-redirect=true" />
```

However, all with all, if this is the real code and you don't actually intend to invoke a bean action, then you're going in completely the wrong direction as to implementing the functional requirement of navigating to a different page by a button. You should be using `<h:button>` instead.

```
<h:button value="Enter" outcome="index" />
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)

Comment: Does h:button support action?

Comment: No, but why should it? You're in your initial code snippet merely navigating and not performing any action and essentially abusing the `h:commandButton` for pure navigation.

Comment: I was giving a simple example here. In my actual code, I want do something in the action of h:commandButton...

Comment: Then just stick to it.