# Primefaces / JSF button's action handler will not trigger the related bean's method

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm very new in using the Primefaces framework.

My problem is, that I want to call a bean method if the user clicks a button, but the method won't be triggered.
Nevertheless, IntelliJ autocompletes the method and I use the bean as item source for another control, that works.

**Parts of Index.htmlx**

```
<h:form id="newLunch">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 300px;">
        <h:outputLabel for="initiator" value="Initiator" />
        <p:inputText id="initiator" />

        ...

        <p:button value="save" actionListener="#{indexBean.onSaveLunch}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**IndexBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBean
{
    public IndexBean()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void onSaveLunch()
    {
        // do some action, will not be triggered
    }
}
```

Thanks for supporting a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the right component and the right attribute. Change `<p:button>` by `<p:commandButton>` and use `action` instead of `actionListener`:

```html
<p:commandButton value="save" action="#{indexBean.onSaveLunch}" />
```

If this doesn't work, then there's another problem within your code that you haven't shown. For that, update the question with your current code or check the reasons from here: [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656/1065197)

More info:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13070537/1065197)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3909267/1065197)

Answer (score 2):

```
    <p:button value="save" actionListener="#{indexBean.onSaveLunch}" />
```

Use Primefaces CommandButton here.

```
    <p:commandButton value="save" actionListener="#{indexBean.onSaveLunch}" />
```

More info [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf)

***Updated:***

The reason your method is not being called because it is not valid for actionListener.

Change your method from

```
  public void onSaveLunch()
        {
            // do some action, will not be triggered
        }
```

to

```
 public void onSaveLunch(ActionEvent event)
    {
        // do some action, will not be triggered
    }
```

Remember to `import import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;` because there is another java swing action event which you don't want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried this before and it didn't work as well. I've retested it just a couple of seconds ago. That's a weird behaviour in my eyes. I know, that is my fault.

Comment: In my IDE's output windows, I see following row every time i click the button: `127.0.0.1 -  -  [18/May/2014:14:30:57 +0000] "POST /base/index.xhtml HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://localhost:8080/base/" [...]"`

Comment: Thanks @Makkx for your update! But the Luiggi Mendoza's idea was (another working) solution.