# How to enter a JSF 2.2 flow with faces-redirect

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, post-redirect-get, faces-flow

I've got a basic flow example working:

```
src/main/webapp
|
|- index.xhtml
|- flow1
   |- flow1-flow.xml
   |- flow1.xhtml
```

index.xhtml has a simple form that enters the flow with a parameter:

```
<h:form>
    Click to enter flow1
    <h:commandButton action="flow1" value="Flow 1">
        <f:param name="testInput" value="hi there"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

flow1.xhtml displays the param and lets you enter a value into flow scope:

```
<h:form>
    Hi this is page 1.
    <h:inputText label="Enter something:" value="#{flowScope.testOutput}"/><br/>
    Request parameter: #{param['testInput']}<br/>
    <h:commandButton action="returnFromFlow1"/>
</h:form>
```

flow1-flow.xml just defines the return node as "returnFromFlow1" and sets it to /index.xhtml.

This seems to be working. I want to implement post-redirect-get when entering the flow so that the browser address bar stays in sync with the view. So I naturally tried action="flow1?faces-redirect=true". This change prevents the flow from executing.. it simply reloads index.xhtml when the button is clicked.

Then I tried action="flow1/flow1.xhtml?faces-redirect=true". This loads the page and redirects as expected, but the flow is not initialized. When I submit the form in the flow, I get an error about flowScope resolving to null.

Doing a little research, I found a tip to set the "to-flow-document-id" to force it to initialize the flow. So I added  to my commandbutton. No change.

Any ideas about how to accomplish this?

Comment: didnt you found an answer by yourself by any chance? I'm trying to sort this out as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "no change"? The flowscope still gets destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

If the only requirement is that the browser address bar stays in sync with the view, you can simply use `<h:button` instead of `<h:commandButton`. This works because `<h:button` uses Javascript to generate a HTTP GET request to start and navigate to the flow. The ID of the flow has to be specified as value of the `outcome` attribute:

***index.xhtml:***

```
<h:form>
    Click to enter flow1
    <h:button outcome="flow1" value="Flow 1">
        <f:param name="testInput" value="hi there" />
    </h:button>
</h:form>
```

### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072025/5223047)

---

If the requirement is that some checks have to be done before the permission to start the flow is granted, you have to manually initialize and navigate to the flow as follows:

***index.xhtml:***

```
<h:form>
    Click to enter flow1
    <h:commandButton action="#{backingBean.startFlow1()}" value="Flow 1" />
</h:form>
```

***flow1.xhtml:***

```
<h:form>
    Hi this is page 1.
    <h:inputText label="Enter something:" value="#{flowScope.testOutput}"/><br/>
    Request parameter: #{flowScope.testInput}<br/>
    <h:commandButton action="returnFromFlow1"/>
</h:form>
```

***BackingBean:***

```
public void startFlow1() {
    if (!permissionGranted) {
        // show "permission denied"
        return;
    }

    final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final Application application = facesContext.getApplication();

    // get an instance of the flow to start
    final String flowId = "flow1";
    final FlowHandler flowHandler = application.getFlowHandler();
    final Flow targetFlow = flowHandler.getFlow(facesContext,
            "", // definingDocumentId (empty if flow is defined in "faces-config.xml")
            flowId);

    // get the navigation handler and the view ID of the flow
    final ConfigurableNavigationHandler navHandler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) application.getNavigationHandler();
    final NavigationCase navCase = navHandler.getNavigationCase(facesContext,
            null, // fromAction
            flowId);
    final String toViewId = navCase.getToViewId(facesContext);

    // initialize the flow scope
    flowHandler.transition(facesContext,
            null, // sourceFlow
            targetFlow,
            null, // outboundCallNode
            toViewId); // toViewId

    // add the parameter to the flow scope
    flowHandler.getCurrentFlowScope()
            .put("testInput", "hi there2!");

    // navigate to the flow by HTTP GET request
    final String outcome = toViewId + "?faces-redirect=true";
    navHandler.handleNavigation(facesContext,
            null, // from action
            outcome);
}
```

**Please note that the parameter can not be added to the button in this case but has to be added to the flow scope instead!
Also note that the redirect to the flow has to be done by [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html#handleNavigation-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead of [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect-java.lang.String-) because the flow scope is terminated otherwise!**

### See also:

- [Can a faces flow be started from within a Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29259227/5223047)
- [Programmatically get navigation case  from
  faces-config.xml by outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013367/5223047)
- [Omnifaces Faces.redirect loses conversation scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24259494/5223047)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm reading the [JSF-2.2 faces-config schema](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd) correctly, you should be able to specify a `<redirect/>` directive in a *faces-config.xml*. So using the following, you should able to achieve a redirect:

```
       <navigation-rule>
           <from-view-id>/pages/test/test.xhtml</from-view-id>
               <navigation-case>
                   <from-outcome>flow1</from-outcome>
                   <to-flow-document-id>flow1.xhtml</to-flow-document-id>
                       <redirect />
              </navigation-case>
       </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I've tried several possible variants of it, and didn't get any results.

Comment: Additionally, if you create a valid navigation rule to flow, and it will by applied during navigation, it will most likely cause an error with accessing uninitialized bean, because flow will not be initialized.

Comment: @T.G - that sounds like a bug because [the api specifically stipulates that `@FlowScoped` beans be instantiated upon entry into a flow by the FlowHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/flow/FlowHandler.html)

Comment: @T.G - Something odd in [the source for the FlowHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/flow/FlowHandlerImpl.java?av=h#FlowHandlerImpl) is that there's nowhere in the implementation or superclass where the flowscoped bean is actually being retrieved. A `getCurrentFlowScope` is defined, but I can't find its usage. Even its definition is suspect in that according to the spec and javadoc, the expectation is that  a new instance should be created on entry into a flow.

Comment: Maybe you should post your stacktrace here

Comment: but there is no such stack trace except entering flow document by traditional navigation rule. There is no way that someone can initialize flowscope bean manually or end its life. FacesFlow is in alpha state - that is what i always say, when someone ask me about what i'm thinking about this feature of JSF. ALPHA PHASE. `GetCurrentFlowScope` is method very usefull however, because thanks to this method i'm able to add transitions from inside  of a flow, to another place in system if there is no connection so application menu don't have to be handled in every single flow definition.

Comment: You could always write a custom FlowHandler @T.G

Comment: i've tried that long time ago. it adds redirect param to flow id or node id, but it get lost during processing later by framework code. Im saying to you - ALPHA PHASE

Comment: I guess a bug filing is in order @T.G

Answer (score 0):

Please run this example i hope it will help you out.

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>flow1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>flow1.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect></redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```