# Omnifaces Faces.redirect loses conversation scope

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, conversation-scope

I have problem with org.omnifaces.util.Faces#redirect and conversation scoped bean:

there is a button

```
<p:commandButton action="#{navigationHandler.gotoCreateCar}"
  actionListener="#{createHandler.init(searchHandler.search())}
  value="#{msg.search}" update=":articleSearchForm">
  <f:param name="cid" value="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

which must do a navigation to createCar page within the same conversation scope after init of my conversation scoped bean: createHandler.

In the NavigationHandler#gotoCreateCar is just a call of Faces.redirect(createCarPage).

If I do like this the parameter cid is not transfered and I lose my conversation.

If I define a navigation rule in faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>createCar</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/portal/createCar.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <redirect />
</navigation-case>
```

and in the NavigationHandler#gotoCreateCar just return the needed outcome - then it works fine.

Maybe I do not understand every detail in the difference between this two navigation approaches. I would be appreciated if somebody could help me to understand the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversation propagation is handled by the navigation handler. The [`Faces#redirect()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#redirect%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) delegates to [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) which does not use the navigation handler. You'd better use [`Faces#navigate()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#navigate%28java.lang.String%29) instead which delegates to [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html?is-external=true#handleNavigation%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
public void gotoCreateCar() {
    // ...

    Faces.navigate("/portal/createCar.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

*(note: no `<navigation-case>` is needed in this case)*

Alternatively, just return exactly that string from the action method.

```
public String gotoCreateCar() {
    // ...

    return "/portal/createCar.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The `Faces#navigate()` is only useful when you're inside a (listener) method which doesn't support returning a navigation case outcome, such as `@PostConstruct` or `preRenderView`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Can you also explain what the difference between ExternalContext#redirect and navigation handler redirect?

Comment: The one doesn't use JSF navigation handler, while the other does.

Comment: So the navigation handler handles the conversation additionally to redirecting and ExternalContext just do the plain redirecting? Sorry, I just try to clarify the question for me.

Comment: Yes. As answered, the conversation propagation is handled by the JSF navigation handler. The `ExternalContext#redirect()` doesn't use the JSF navigation handler. It just sets "plain vanilla" a HTTP `Location` header on the response without any manipulation of the given path. The JSF navigation handler supports more fine grained control over this, e.g. it can interpret the given path as a (relative) JSF view ID and perform some additional actions based on e.g. the current conversation state, or the additional specific parameters such as `faces-redirect`, `includeViewParams`, etc.

Comment: Note that the blueish texts in my answer are actually links to docs (as usual). Click them to see and read the docs. It's also explained over there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I must read the source code to see all the details :) and documentation also...