# Can a faces flow be started from within a Servlet?

Tags: jsf-2.2, flow-scope

I have a service, accessed by a servlet, which redirects the user to a login screen. The backing beans' scope is currently being changed from @ConversationScoped to @FlowScoped, as it's easier to handle.

Is there a way to initialize a faces flow directly from within a servlet, without the indirection through an implicit action or a JSF forward/redirect?

I am aware that @FlowScope is a JSF (2.2) scope and I was wondering if there might be a way to e.g. extend the FacesServlet or something similar.

As a workaround, I currently just added view with a button, which makes a JSF forward to enter the flow directory, but I am trying to avoid this.

*Update* 
I tried many approaches to 'automatically' forward into a flow, without having to click on any button, but I always get a `No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped`. Here my approaches:

1. `f:viewAction`

   ```
   <f:metadata>
     <f:viewAction action="myFlow" />
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   This one seems to be executed too early (in any case).
2. `f:event`

   ```
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.forwardToMyFlow()}" />
   ```

   The method in the bean returns the same outcome as in `f:viewAction`.
3. Navigation case

   ```
   <navigation-rule>
     <from-view-id>/myView.xhtml</from-view-id>
     <navigation-case>
       <from-outcome>myFlow</from-outcome>
       <to-view-id>/myFlow/myFlow.xhtml</to-view-id>
       <redirect />
       <to-flow-document-id />
     </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>
   ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a front controller to a flow although, If I'm reading the specification properly, you should be able to directly reference the first view of the flow; the spec says that the necessary `@FlowScoped` beans must be initialized on entry to the first node in a flow

Comment: @kolossus Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay, I have been off for a while. I found the reference in the spec, you mentioned, but I still could not get it to work. I always get a `ContextNotActiveException`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution, after reading specs and fiddling around with flows! 
I am having a page where I simply have:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.initFlow}" />
</f:metadata>
```

So far so good, but the trick is inside the method, where you have to 'manually' initialize the desired flow by doing the following:

```
public String initFlow(){
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   FlowHandler handler = context.getApplication().getFlowHandler();
   handler.transition(context, null, handler.getFlow(context, "", "flow-name"), null, "");
   return "flow-name";
}
```

The `transition` method 'activates' the named flow and makes it available, so that you then can forward to the entry point of the flow.
**Please note**, that even if it looks like a normal forward, `viewAction` always does a redirect!