# Programmatically get navigation case <to-view-id> from faces-config.xml by outcome

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, faces-config

Is there any way to get the `<to-view-id>` of a navigation case in the backing bean?

Let's say I want to get the `<to-view-id>` from the outcome `success`, which is supposed to be `page1.xhtml`. Is there any helper function?

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>start.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{pageController.processPage1}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page1.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{pageController.processPage2}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page2.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

If it helps, I'm using PrettyFaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a `NavigationCase`, from a `ConfigurableNavigationHandler`. The `NavigationCase` represents a configured navigation case and you can get all the info you need from this object. Observe:

```
 ConfigurableNavigationHandler configNavHandler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)ctxt.getApplication().getNavigationHandler(); //assumes you already have an instance of FacesContext, named ctxt
 NavigationCase navCase = configNavHandler.getNavigationCase(ctxt,null,"success");

 String toViewId = navCase.getToViewId(ctx); // the <to-view-id>
```