# How to test if a JSF navigation case exists during rendering of a page

Tags: jsf, navigation

I am basically having a Template I want to reuse for several of my pages. They all have a look and feel in common where they share a menu that allows them to login and navigate to a Home page. The issue is with the Home page:

1. When there exists an `index` (`index.xhtml`) local to the current page (not the template), then use that as the default. When my template is called from `/tools/page` (`/tools/page.xhtml`), then it will point to `/tools/index` (`/tools/index.xthml`). With relative path, I can drop the `/tools`.
2. Fall back to `/index` (`/index.xhtml`).

Example:

```xml
<p:menubar>
  <p:menuitem icon="fa fa-home" outcome="/index" value="Home" 
    rendered="#{not outcomeExists('index')}" />
  <p:menuitem icon="fa fa-home" outcome="index" value="Home"
    rendered="#{outcomeExists('index')}" />
  <p:menuitem icon="fa fa-user" value="#{login.name}"/>
</p:menubar>
```

Of course, I want to translate true JSF Navigation rules for testing if it exists or not, so it will automatically look for index.xhtml, index.jsf, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying - and came to this solution, where have to expose following method on a CDI Bean used within my JSF page:

```
public boolean outcomeExists(String outcome) {
  FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  ConfigurableNavigationHandler configNavHandler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)ctx.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();  
  NavigationCase navCase = configNavHandler.getNavigationCase(ctx,null,outcome);
  return navCase != null && navCase.getToViewId(ctx) != null; // the <to-view-id>
}
```

This was adapted from - [Programmatically get navigation case <to-view-id> from faces-config.xml by outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29011040/744133)