# ConfigurableNavigationHandler get navigation case for combination of outcome and origin action

Tags: jsf, navigation

As seen in this question [Programmatically get navigation case <to-view-id> from faces-config.xml by outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011040/programmatically-get-navigation-case-to-view-id-from-faces-config-xml-by-outco) 
i use getNavigationCase to get my view id based on the outcome, and in my case also on the fromAction.

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler configNavHandler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) context.getApplication()
            .getNavigationHandler();
    NavigationCase navCase = configNavHandler.getNavigationCase(context, fromAction, outcome);
```

The problem is no navigation case is found, even if i have a navigation case matching perfectly fromAction and outcome

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/jsp/example/exampleSource.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>loadSuccess</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/jsp/example/exampleDetails.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    ...
</navigation-rule>
```

It happens only with the navigation rules with a from-view-id field.
The simpler ones work. Example:

```
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>GOTO_SEARCH</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/jsp/search.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
```

Comment: Is exapmple the correct path?

Comment: It was a typo here, i'm 100% sure the path is correct.