# How GET and POST method is called in JSF?

Tags: jsp, http, jsf, jsf-2

I have simple h:commnadButton den how to know that this is get or post method?
Or how to differentiate the get and post method in jsf page?

Comment: That has more to do with http rather than JSF.. Anyway, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)

Comment: @XtremeBiker Whether h:commandButton does a GET or a POST is 100% a JSF question, as your own citation shows.

Comment: @EJP in fact, it is, but firstly I would begin looking at what `h:commandButton` generates at client side. Once there, you'll be able to understand if it is a GET or a POST request. Web frameworks are great tools, but most of the problems start when people learn them without worrying about what they are doing behind. That was the point of my comment. Anyway, your answer is OK

Answer (score 1):

h:commandButton causes a POST.

I've never found a JSF situation where I needed to know in the page whether the request was a GET or a POST, but it's available in EL via the 'request' object.

Comment: plz just give me the simple example.

Comment: Why? Can't you look up the EL request properties for yourself?