# CommandButton not working in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I have a maven/web application with JSF Framework.

This is the code for the button:

```
<h:form>
     <h:commandButton id="button1" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right"/> 
</h:form>
```

and this is from the navigation file(`faces-configx.xml`):

```
<navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>button1</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/signin.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

When I click the button, it doesnt work, it doesnt take me to the signin.xhtml page. Why is that? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Post-Redirect-Get pattern. When doing this, the JSF lifecycle, specifically in phase 5 Invoke Application, it will check that the return of the action is **an empty string** since you haven't defined an output from the `action` attribute in your `<h:commandButton>`:

```
<h:commandButton id="button1" value="Sign in" action="" />
                                              ^-------^
                                              not written, JSF assumes this
```

JSF will search this outcome in faces-config.xml and fire the navigation rule, if exists.

With this in mind, you have 3 alternatives:

1. Set the outcome to a valid navitagion rule:

   ```
   <navigation-rule>
       <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
       <navigation-case>
           <from-outcome>signin</from-outcome>
           <to-view-id>logout.xhtml</to-view-id>
       </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>
   ```

   And in Facelets:

   ```
   <h:commandButton value="Sign in" action="signin" />
   ```
2. Create a proper managed bean which has a method that returns a String that matches with the proper navigation case:

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @RequestScoped
   public class FooBean {
       public String signin() {
           return "signin";
       }
   }
   ```

   And in Facelets:

   ```
   <h:commandButton value="Sign in" action="#{fooBean.signin}" />
   ```
3. A more proper solution for this case: don't use Post-Redirect-Get pattern, instead use direct navigation (Redirect-Get) through `<h:button>` (no form required).

   ```
   <h:button value="Sign in" outcome="signin" />
   ```

   Code above assumes signin.xhtml file exists in the same path of the file where this code is placed. This is:

   ```
   - webapp <-- root folder of the web pages of the app
     - another_folder <-- some folder
     + file.xhtml <-- file that contains <h:button>
     + signin.xhtml <-- file to navigate
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! Lets say, that I want to use alternative 1. How do I use `class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right"` with the `<h:commandButton>` ?

Comment: @Carlton I omitted adding CSS since it's not part of the main problem. Just add the necessary CSS to your HTML and JSF components with no problems.

Comment: I tried as you told me, alternativ 1. But the button still wont work? Why is that? Could there be something elsewhere that prevents the button to navigate me to another page?

Comment: Yes, thanks, my faces-config.xml file is exactly like that. The navigation between other pages(which I can access from my navbar or footer) is working just fine. But I can not make the navigation form the button to work. I tried adding `<h:form></h:form>` around the commandButton, and then it worked. Do I need to have form for commandButton?

Comment: @Carlton I never meant to tell you to use `<h:commandButton>` without the `<h:form>`. Any `UICommand` like `<h:commandButton>` and `<h:commandLink>` **needs** to be placed inside a `<h:form>`, otherwise it won't work. I wrongly assumed you already know this. Also, in the `<h:button>` example, I explicitly post that no form is required to make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help, I really do appreciate it. I am new to webprogramming, this is our first course in that area so I keep forgetting these small things, hehe. Sorry for that. Once again, thank you so much hope you are having a great day!

Comment: You're welcome. Keep practicing, that's the key to remember this small things :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're not using the commandButton correctly.

I think this question can help you:

[Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)