# valueChangeListener, onchange and auto-submission of form using JSF

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2.2, valuechangelistener

For a simple html page like this:

```
<form action="success.html" >

        <input type="text" value="SomeValue" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

Any change of the value results in ***auto-submit*** of the form to navigate to `success.html`

Consider the following snippet in JSF 2.x:

```
<h:form >

        <h:panelGrid columns="3">

            <h:outputLabel value="Name: " />
            <h:inputText id="inputname" binding="#{zipAutoFill.inputName}" 
                                        required="true"/>
            <h:message for="inputname"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="Zip Code: " />
            <h:inputText id="inputzip" 
                         binding="#{zipAutoFill.inputZip}" 
                valueChangeListener="#{zipAutoFill.zipAutoFillListener}"
                                        onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
                                        <h:message for="inputzip"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="City: " />
            <h:inputText id="inputcity" binding="#{zipAutoFill.inputCity}" />
            <h:message for="inputcity"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="State: " />
            <h:inputText id="inputstate" binding="#{zipAutoFill.inputState}" />
            <h:message for="inputstate"/>

            <h:commandButton  id="submitbutton" value="Submit" action="page02"/>

        </h:panelGrid>


</h:form>
```

Based on the zip code filled in by the user(and so resulting in a change of value), the fields city and state will accordingly be populated.

However, after auto-submit, it doesn't navigate to `page02.xhtml`. What am I missing?

Comment: This question is ambiguous. Which problem exactly have you observed? 1) "Page URL doesn't change to that of page02.xhtml", or 2) "Page content doesn't change to that of page02.xhtml", or perhaps both? By the way, all those `binding` things are really scary, unless for some "extreme debugging" reasons. You'd better really remove them all and stop binding components to a managed bean.

Comment: @BalusC: It's not the URL change. I know very well that page URL does not change unless faces-redirect=true is added to the query string of the navigation URL. The question is why the contents of the second page are not shown in case of auto-submit in JSF whereas they happen with ordinary html. With onchange = "document.getElementById('submitbutton').click()"; it doesn't happen either.

Comment: @BalusC: i am using the binding attribute as to understand the lifecycle by debugging.

Comment: You'd better not include them in the question as that's misleading to starters. Instead, create a true http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example where you use simple HTML, the reason behind the navigation after submit is related to the `action` attribute, which is specified with the name of the page you want to send your data to it `<form action="success.html" >`, so your `this.form.submit()` will send the form data to the `success.html` and navigate to it.

To understand the reason why your second page is not shown in case of auto-submit using JSF you could take a look at the generated HTML. In your JSF example, and because you are using [`<h:commandButton>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandButton.html),  the HTML generated will look something like this (for simplicity I assumed your form id is `form` and your **current page** is `page01.xhtml`):

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/yourcontextpath/page01.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form" />
    .....

    <input type="submit" name="form:submitbutton" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Thus, you can notice that the `action` attribute of the generated HTML is set to your current page `action="/yourcontextpath/page01.xhtml"`, which means that any call to the JavaScript `submit()` will send the form data to the current page which is in our case `page01.xhtml` (unlike the first example, where the form data was sent to another page `success.html`).

In a nutshell, You will not have the same behavoir, because the HTML code is not the same (comparing the first example, and the generated HTML) and the main difference is related to the page specified in the form's action attribute.

**NB:** If you submit using the `<h:commandButton>`, the result will be different, because JSF will use the outcome of the commandButton's action attribute to navigate to `page02.xhtml` as specified in `<h:commandButton  id="submitbutton" value="Submit" action="page02"/>`

### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)

Comment: I know that it could be done with ajaxifying the page. In fact the author(i have taken this example from a book) has illustrated both of the 2 features. Thank you for your response but it doesn't answer my query. How will the contents of the second page be shown?

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari your query was "after auto-submit, it doesn't navigate to page02.xhtml. What am I missing?", in a ddition to your comment "The question is why the contents of the second page are not shown in case of auto-submit" . So, if I understand correctly it means that you are looking for the reason why you're not navigating to the other page, and that's what I was explaining in the fisrt part of my answer, the ajax was just an opinion (I thought you are new in JSF so I tried to be more helpful) and not the core of the answer. Anyway, I updated my answer and deleted the ajax part.

Comment: I upvoted you. But if submit using h:commandButton, i.e using onchange = "document.getElementById('submitbutton').click()"; it doesn't happen either. What am i then missing.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari that should normally work. But, when you used `document.getElementById('submitbutton').click()` the form will not even submit because you are not using the client id of your `h:commandButton` (you can notice that if you used *firebug*: you will get an error like `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`). Thus, If you use it like this: `document.getElementById('form:submitbutton').click()` while `form` is the `id` of your form, you will get the desired result : submit + redirect

Comment: Actually some other project is deployed onto the server. I will let you definitely within some time duration. And thanks for helping me.