# Navigate to a JSF page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, navigation, jsf-1.2

I have a JSF button which calls a Javascript function when it is pressed, that function is doing some work and at the end it redirects to another page, it looks like this:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" onclick="myFunction()">
</h:commandButton>
```

And the function looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    // .....
    window.location.href = "/page2.faces";
}
```

The HTML code is generated fine when the page is opened:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="form1:button1" name="form1:button1" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

The function is executed but the redirection does not work, it remains on the same page. Is there a way to redirect from a Javascript function?

-------UPDATE--------

The `form` tag is generated as follows:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/myProject/page1.faces" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="form">
```

The `action` is the same as the first page, seems like when I click the button it navigates to the same page because of this.

Comment: Should work. Any errors on the browser developer tools console?

Comment: There are no errors, it just stays on the same page

Comment: Something really strange is happening, if I click on the button it stays on the same page but if I set a breakpoint and execute the function step by step using the Browser dev tools at the end it successfully redirects to the other page.

Comment: Bad usage of an `h:commandButton`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that, I'm using JSF 1.2 and seems like the `<h:button>` tag only is supported in JSF 2.x

Comment: what happens if you throw out the `action` parameter of the form?

Comment: The `action` parameter is automatically generated by the JSF runtime and it always points to the same page, if I remove the `form` tag completely then it redirects to the other page, but I need the form because some components require a form to work properly.