# JSF2 - Navigating to a .xhtml file in a parent-folder

Tags: jsf, netbeans, xhtml

At the beginning of my JSF Web Application I am directed to index.xhtml by NetBeans.

From here I successfully navigated to a .xhtml file in subfolder using the following code:

```
<h:commandButton value="Go to Question 1" action="QuestionPages/question_1"/>
```

Within this .xhtml file I wanted to include a "Homepage" button navigate back to the original index.xhtml file.

To do this I tried the following code:

```
<h:commandButton value="Homepage" action="../index" />
```

This did not work. I have also tried several other variations of this with no success.

Here is the error message:

[image]

I have attached an image of the file system, as it appears in NetBeans, for clarity.

[image]

A solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tip 1: next time you get an error message, use it as search keyword. Results almost guaranteed. Tip 2: better use <h:button> if it's pure page-to-page navigation. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton

Comment: Apologies and thank you for the help!