# Navigate to other page using POST request in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, http-post

In JSF, I am doing a GET request like follows:

```
<p:button value="Select Document" icon="fa fa-save" outcome="index">
    <f:param name="documento"
             value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDigrc.documento}" />
</p:button>
```

I don't want to display that value in the URL so I am trying to make a POST request instead. How can I accomplish that?

In my project I am using PrimeFaces 5.3, JSF 2.2 and OmniFaces 1.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `commandButton` instead of `button`.

The POST equivalent of exactly your GET snippet is below:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Select Document" icon="fa fa-save" action="index">
        <f:param name="documento"
                 value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDigrc.documento}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

You only need to keep in mind that the URL change won't be reflected in address bar and that the target page is not bookmarkable anymore. This shouldn't be a problem if the target page is not idempotent, but it doesn't look like to be one ("SELECT" is always idempotent).

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope/)

Comment: That worked but when I make a POST request from search.jsf to index.jsf the URL is not updated to index.jsf. It stays as search.jsf. Can I make it change? Also, could you please explain what does it mean for a page to be idempotent? Thanks @BalusC

Comment: See 2nd and 3rd "See also" links for this spinoff question.

Comment: Yep just saw it haha. It is using ?faces-redirect=true. Thanks you sir!

Comment: I hope you already thought about how exactly the page should behave when enduser bookmarks/copypastes/shares the URL into a different browser window or even session.